# vb not able to click drop down and select value on website - web scraping

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull some data from a website. I want to click a drop down button on the website "Select Payment Frequency" and select "YEARLY" from it. However, I am unable to select it. I have tried all combinations but am not able to do it. Please find below the code I am using.

```
Sub PC()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Top = 0
ie.Left = 0
ie.Width = 800
ie.Height = 600
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate (http://www.iciciprulife.com/public/Cash_Advantage/buy-Cash-Advantage-online.htm?UID=497)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Do While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Loop
ie.document.getElementById("datepicker2").Value = “12/10/1997”
ie.document.getElementById("imobile").Value = "9987587821"
ie.document.getElementById("iEmail").Value = "jainsweta29@gmail.com"
ie.document.getElementById("closebalfund").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
ie.document.getElementById("premium").Value = "24000"
ie.document.getElementById("paymentFrequency").Value = "YEARLY"
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value of the combo by text (i.e. `.Value="YEARLY"`) fails more often than not, because it must be case sensitive, sensitive to space characters that you dont see, etc...

S safer way to select from a combo is by using the index (position) of the item you want to select. In that combo, it is at position 3, so the index is 2, in zero-based indexing. You could try this:

```
ie.document.getElementById("paymentFrequency").SelectedIndex = 2
```

Yet another thing that I suspect in your code is that I dont see where the variable Premium is defined. I guess it must be defined as integer, somewhere.

Comment: Thanks ASH. I have tried the code suggested by you. Yet it is not working. Nothing happens on the premium. Also, sorry for the premium part. I have edited the code.

Comment: *Nothing happens on the page.